# the live server extention is not functioning, What should I do now? I tried to change the extention settings but coudn't fix it

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

The error promt says : "Server is started at 5500 but failed to open in browser preview. Got browser preview extension installed?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setting, you can navigate to the Extensions and to the Live Server Compiler section. There, uncheck the box labeled "Live Server > Settings: Use Browser Preview"
If this doesn't help, try reinstalling the extension and check if vscode is running on the latest version